# How to convert variant value into integer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Below is my code:

```
var
  i : integer;
  ...
  ...
if not VarIsNull(TcxLookupComboBox(Sender).EditValue) then
begin
  i := Integer(TcxLookupComboBox(Sender).EditValue);
end;
```

I can use `VarToStr` to convert variant into string but there is no `VarToInt` in Delphi for this. So, I have converted it like this `Integer(TcxLookupComboBox(Sender).EditValue)`. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Just assign it as `i := TcxLookupComboBox(Sender).EditValue`. Compiler will do the conversion for you.

Comment: You should read about Variants before using them.

Comment: What type of value is in EditValue?

Comment: +1 no need to downvote imho. I guess `EditValue` is a variant? (if not, it does not make sence to use variants to convert to integer).

Comment: @jpfollenius - Yes, EditValue is variant.

Comment: @TLama: you could make that an answer, maybe with a link to the documentation explaining variants

Comment: @nkp Yes, but what type of value is in the variant?

Comment: @jpfollenius, nkp The point of David's question is that if `EditValue` contains `'abc'` you're not going to be able to convert it to an integer. However, if it contains `123` then simple assignment as indicated in [TLama's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864212/how-to-convert-variant-value-into-integer#comment36731048_23864212) is all that's needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Variant_Types

Specifically check the Variant Type Conversions section.

You should be able to assign is directly using implicit type casting. As in Delphi just handles it for you.

As an example:

```
var
  theVar: Variant;
  theInt: integer;
begin

  theVar := '123';
  theInt := theVar;
  showmessage(IntToStr(theint));
end;
```

This works without issue.

To ensure that your data is an integer and that it is safe to do at runtime (as in to make use that you didn't have a string value in the variant, which would result in a runtime error) then have a look at the Val function: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Val

Hope this helps.

Comment: TryStrToInt is what should be used rather than Val

Comment: For the sake of code clarity it sometimes is not desirable to use auxiliary integer variable to cast variant to integer.

Answer (score 10):

This might help:

```
function VarToInt(const AVariant: Variant): integer;
begin
  Result := StrToIntDef(Trim(VarToStr(AVariant)), 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(VarToInt(NULL)));
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(VarToInt(' 124   ')));
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(VarToInt(13.87)));
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(VarToInt('Edijs')));
end;
```

Results are: 0, 124, 0 and 0. You can make it to work with floats tho.

Comment: Is seems a little overkill to cast variant to string to check if it can be casted to integer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Delphi lacks of simple function like this below:

```pascal
function VarToIntDef(const V: Variant; const ADefault: Integer = 0): Integer;
begin
  if V = NULL then
    Result := ADefault
  else
    Result := V;
end;
```